# Button Validation Logic

Tags: validation, button

I came across a simple example for validating that when a button is clicked, it verifies that something is true or false in the Record before allowing the normal button logic.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")}

if(ISBLANK({!Opportunity.Amount})) {
alert ("Opportunity Amount cannot be blank");
} else {
*** would be normal result here ****
*** such as:    window.open('/500/e?retURL=%2F500%2Fo&etcetcetc...'); ***
}
```

But it complains about "Opportunity" not being defined.  Can someone help..?

ADDED:   Button is located on a standard Opportunity page layout.

ADDED:  New code (minus the ELSE section)...

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}

{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")}

var t = { ! ISBLANK( Opportunity.Amount ) };
alert(t + ' ' + typeof t);

/*
if( !Opportunity.Company_Is_NEXT_STEP__c  ) {
alert ("NEXT STEP checkbox must be selected (just an example error)");
*/

} else {
*****  else routine - works fine *****
}
```

RESULT OF THE above is (verbatim):  "Unexpected token !"

Comment: Where is this button located? On an Opportunity Page Layout, an Opportunity List View or somewhere else?

Comment: Page Layout.  It's actually being used for DocuSign, and we want to be sure they fill in certain fields before clicking the button.  Seemed like the simple solution, just not sure why it's complaining about this.

Comment: I actually removed the ISBLANK in favor of just checking the boolean value... trying what you say now.

Comment: Can you paste the whole visualforce code ?Also if any controller please have it in question .

Comment: Done posting new code.

Comment: I know what you mean +Phil_R in VisualForce, but not in this case.  :-/

Comment: @PhilR & eyescream: Your comments seem like they might be better off as answers.

Comment: Everything I find online SEEMS to indicate I have to make a VisualForce page to make this work.  Is that true??

Comment: @AMM - I would suggest adding that last comment to your original post so it has greater visibility and clarify that button is currently on a standard page layout and not a VF page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check what does this return for you:

```
var value = '{!Opportunity.Amount}';
var blankTest = {!ISBLANK(Opportunity.Amount)};
alert (value + "\r\n" + typeof blankTest + ' ' + blankTest);
```

(note that you had syntax error, ISBLANK should be within the {!...})

RE:  "Unexpected token !"

No, you can't have code like `{ ! ...` and expect it to work! Maybe you did it for nice formatting but there's no way it will work... Curly brace, immediately followed by exclamation mark....

---

[image]

Comment: WIth spacing removed, it just complains "Unexpected tokan }".  I assume this may have to do with the Standard Controller item. (?)   Seems like such a simple thing I want to do, makes it clear to me how swiss-cheesed my knowledge is.   I have EXACTLY what you show in your Answer now and it complains of the end bracket.

Comment: I removed the brackets entirely from your code and it complains the same.  I obviously have done something more (perhaps in my ELSE?!).   I will dig deeper.  :-(   Thanks.

Comment: Posting NEW code in posting.. it's 4 lines total....

Comment: THANK YOU, @eyescream.   I discovered I left the end bracket of my original IF at the end of the entire routine after cutting the ELSE out entirely.    :-/  You'll note the trailing bracket (and ELSE) in my second code.   (sigh)

Comment: My head is hung in shame.

Comment: Too late, I'm posting this image as a token of my sheer frustration :P

Comment: For the hell of asking:  What if Opportunity.Amount is a checkbox?   That is why I had taken out ISBLANK.  It doesn't like ISBLANK.  -0-- NEVER MIND, removing ISBLANK was right originally (for a Boolean).   Thanks again.

Comment: Since `Amount` is standard field it will always be of type Currency :) For checkboxes (standard and custom) ISBLANK etc. doesn't make sense, they're never undefined (`null` if you like). Start the wizard of creating new checkbox, you'll notice there HAS to be something as the default value.